# How to stop Windows service programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

About programming Windows services: how to stop my windows service?

Here is a very simplified example code(C#):

```
// Here is my service class (MyTestService.cs).
public class MyTestService:ServiceBase{

    // Constructor.
    public MyTestService(){
         this.ServiceName = "My Test Service";
         return;
    }
};

//  My application class (ApplicationClass.cs).
public static class ApplicationClass{

    // Here is main Main() method.
    public static void Main(){
        // 1. Creating a service instance
        // and running it using ServiceBase.
        MyTestService service = new MyTestService();
        ServiceBase.Run(service);
        // 2. Performing a test shutdown of a service.
        service.Stop();
        Environment.Exit(0);
        return;
    };
};
```

So: I've just created "My Test Service" started it and stopped. But when I'm looking into my Services.msc - "My Test Service" is continues to running and stops ONLY when I click a "Stop" link. Why? - why *service.Stop()* command does nothing?

ServiceController.Stop() also does nothing!

How can I stop my service from Main() method?

Comment: Make sure you are running your application as an administrator.

Answer (score 22):

The `Stop`-function sends a stop-signal. It does not wait till the signal is received and processed.

You will have to wait till the Stop-signal has done it's work. You can do that by calling `WaitForStatus`:

```
service.Stop();
service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
```

See for more info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.waitforstatus(v=vs.71).aspx

`Environment.Exit` is a nasty one. DO NOT USE IT! It aborts your application the hard way, without performing any cleanup in finally blocks, without calling finalizer methods by the GC, it terminates all other forground threads, etc. I can imagine that your application is aborted before the stop-signal even left your application.

Answer (score 12):

I am using following functions in my project

```
    public static ServiceController GetService(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices();
        return services.FirstOrDefault(_ => Contracts.Extensions.CompareStrings(_.ServiceName, serviceName));
    }

    public static bool IsServiceRunning(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceControllerStatus status;
        uint counter = 0;
        do
        {
            ServiceController service = GetService(serviceName);
            if (service == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            status = service.Status;
        } while (!(status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped ||
                   status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) &&
                 (++counter < 30));
        return status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running;
    }

    public static bool IsServiceInstalled(string serviceName)
    {
        return GetService(serviceName) != null;
    }

    public static void StartService(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceController controller = GetService(serviceName);
        if (controller == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        controller.Start();
        controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
    }

    public static void StopService(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceController controller = GetService(serviceName);
        if (controller == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        controller.Stop();
        controller.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
    }
```

Comment: The name Contracts doesnt exist in the current context

Comment: @Thompson: Then use ```services.FirstOrDefault(_ => _.ServiceName == serviceName)```

Answer (score 3):

In your code example `service.Stop()` and `ServiceController.Stop()` commands does nothing because they are not called while service is running since `ServiceBase.Run(service)` is blocking operation and it returns only on stop of the service.