# Windows Service Restart

Tags: c#, windows-services, timeout

I would like to know how I can restart my windows service the way I want it to be.

I have this solution:

```
private const int RestartTimeout = 60000; // 1 minute

 public void Control(string serviceName)
 {
     service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
 } 

public bool RestartService()
        {
            try
            {
                Control("MyService");
                service.Refresh();
                if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
                {
                    mytimer.Enabled = false;
                    service.Stop();
                    int i = 0;
                    service.Refresh();

                    while (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped || service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.StopPending)
                    {
                        i++;
                        Thread.Sleep(100);
                        if (i >= RestartTimeout / 100)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    service.Start();
                    return true;
                }

                service.Start();

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
```

I got a timeout error when it reaches the while loop. I guess it's because the service has been stopped?

What I'm really trying to achieve here is to Stop the service and then sleep for 1 minute before starting the service again.

Please help.Thanks!

Comment: Just out of interest, what's the use-case for restarting the service?

Comment: My service would normally run for only 3-5 minutes, but if exceeds to that, it will restart itself to prevent it to hang or eat resources on my machine. Thanks

Comment: Can't it just sleep when it's not doing anything?

Comment: Right,that will definitely work, but I wanted to try restarting it too.

Comment: @SyntaxError - try using WaitForStatus, instead of Sleep -  see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16317378/how-to-stop-windows-service-programmaticaly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way (of course you need to start your application with admin privileges!):

Small advice: Split your problems into multiple parts (multiple methods), because if a bug appears you can narrow it down to a small amount of lines.

```
    public void RestartService(string serviceName)
    {
        if (StopService(serviceName) == true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(60000);
            if (StartService(serviceName) == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Service started succesfully");
            }
       }
    }

    private bool StartService(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            service.Start();
            service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Running);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }

    private bool StopService(string serviceName)
    {
        ServiceController service = new ServiceController(serviceName);
        try
        {
            if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                service.Stop();
                service.WaitForStatus(ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped);
                return true;
            }
            else if (service.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. This one works, but only if I set the Thread sleep to 20000-25000. More than that, it will not proceed to the starting of the service again. I have 10 seconds Initialization time. Is this a timeout issue? 35 secs Timeout?

Comment: Usually services timeout after 30 secs (that's the default value). You can extend this period by changing a key in the registry: 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control` -> `ServicesPipeTimeout`. Change the value from `30000` to let's say `100000`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar asp.net project, i used this code and this was working.

```
try
{
ServiceController service = new ServiceController(service_name, computer_name);
if (service.Status != ServiceControllerStatus.Running)
{
return false;
}
else
{
service.Stop();
Thread.Sleep(60000);
service.Start();
}
}
catch (Exception exc)
{
return false;
}
```

I know you could do that but sometimes its better just think simple.

Comment: I still got a timeout error when it reaches the Thread.Sleep(60000).:(