# Restart Windows service from another service

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am developing a Windows Service that will control a group of windows application and run them on scheduler given from webservice.
I am not able to Start/Stop the services due to security issues. I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23096969/start-stop-a-windows-service-from-another-windows-service) but it did not work.

Comment: Your question is really "how do I perform operations that I am not permitted to do?". An uphill battle in any secure OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try use WMI for manupulation of windows service state. Read [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28161/Using-WMI-to-manipulate-services-Install-Uninstall)

Comment: I am sorry, i have edited the question, i have typed by mistake that i am building windows application, what i meant is that i am building windows service controlling other service